# How to Fix Genymotion openGL error?

Tags: drivers, graphics-card, opengl, android-x86

I am trying to open genymotion,after starting  it shows the following error: 
[image]

i saw in various website/blog that this error gets resolved after updating the video card driver.Unfortunately i am using a old motherboard which has ATI Radeon 3000 Graphics and i don't have any external GPU.I'm using windows 8.1 OS and my graphics driver is also updated to the latest version available in the manufacturer site(Although i didn't find windows 8.1 version driver for my card,so i'm using win7 version driver for ATI Radeon 3000 Graphics).so, is there any workaround for this problem??
any help is greatly appreciated.

PS- My internal GPU supports OpenGL 2.0 and Directx 10.0

Comment: [same question here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23560545/genymotion-opengl-error), just update your graphic card's driver

Answer (score 2):

First things first, OpenGL is not a library. It's a drawing API for talking with the graphics drivers to make the GPU do nice things.

As such, OpenGL comes as part of the graphics drivers. Unfortunately Microsoft decided that they don't like OpenGL and would not ship drivers fully equipped with modern OpenGL profiles through Windows' built in driver update mechanism. Oh, yes, they added legacy support for OpenGL-1.4 (which was specified in 2002), thank you very much.

So you have to take things into your own hands. First step: Go to the control panel and open the Hardware Manager. In the section `Graphics Cards` you'll find the name of your GPU. Most likely it will be made by one of Intel, Nvidia, AMD or ATI.

Depending on who made it you can find the drivers on:

- Intel: http://downloadcenter.intel.com/default.aspx
- NVidia: http://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx
- AMD / ATI: http://support.amd.com/en-us/download

---

Select the drivers appropriate for your system, download and install them.
or how to check current version.
Since OpenGL is not a library the truly limiting factor is the GPU in your system. If your GPU doesn't OpenGL-2 you're SOL. However you'd have a really, really old GPU for that and Windows-8 would not even boot on a system with such a GPU that old. Update your GPU drivers and you should be fine.